# tikz Math Library: Why does this operation "755 / 100" produce 7.54999 and not 7.55?

Tags: tikz-pgf, calculations, tikzlibrary

Here is a code example.

```
\tikzmath{
    \x = 755;
    \x = \x / 100;
}

Output: \x
```

I expect my value stored in \x to be 7.55, but it is instead 7.54999.

Is there some setting to make the result be what I'd expect?

**Edit**

I made a command based on what Sandy G suggested.

```
\newcommand{\floatfix}[1]{
    \pgfmathroundto{#1}\xdef#1{\pgfmathresult}
}
```

Now when I run:

```
\tikzmath{
    \x = 755;
    \x = \x / 100;
}
\floatfix{\x}
Output: \x
```

I get 7.55

Comment: Use a better floating point library.

Comment: why do you expect 7.55 ? a digital computer can't store 7.55  exactly anyway so you'll always get an approximation. If you got 7.4999 as in your title that would be pretty bad but 7.54999 -7.55 isn't going to be visible most likely, although as egreg says you could use an option to use a more acurate arithmetic

Comment: @DavidCarlisle 7.4999 was a typo. Should of been 7.54999. I am displaying these values so I want to see 7.55. I suppose I could use something like siunitx to manually round the numbers, but I wanted to avoid extra tedium. Are there any other libraries out there that would produce 7.55 instead?

Comment: If you want to print then you need to round. You can use `\fpeval{round(\x,2)}` to gt 7.55 that's built in to latex-dev or in latex you need the xfp package util thnxt relase)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle a digital computer certainly *can* store 7.55. Indeed multiple digital computers are doing that right now for all the 7.55 values which are on this page. What matters here is *how* the computer is trying to store it.

Comment: @JBentley yes I know:-) but a discussion about ieee double format and/or tex scaled point arithmetic seemed a bit off topic so it seemed simpler to lie a bit in the above comment. I lie a bit less in the version in the answer I think.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One fix is to use `\pgfmathroundto`:

```
\tikzmath{
    \x = 755;
    \x = \x / 100;
}
\pgfmathroundto{\x}

Output: \pgfmathresult
```

[image]

Comment: I like this suggestion. Would it be possible to store the value that \pgfmathresult holds in \x?

Comment: @Jon: You could use `\pgfmathroundto{\x}\xdef\x{\pgfmathresult}Output: \x`

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 10):

tikz (by default, unless you use the `fp` library) uses TeX dimension arithmetic, so you are seeing the result of

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\dimen0=755pt
\divide\dimen0 by 100
\the\dimen0
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

In any floating (or fixed) point calculation the final decimal places are arbitrary, a more exact fp library may get closer but you can not store 7.55 exactly either as a floating point double  or as a multiple of TeX scaled points, so some rounding error is not unexpected.